# Pause or sleep AsyncTask without affect to UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Can I sleep or stop AsycTask's execution **without affect to UI**? Is there any way **other than creating a new Thread** to achieve this (**I am sure this doesn't affect UI though**)?

**Explanation:**

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<....>{

 @Override
  ..doInbackground(){
   //do something
     for(....){
          //sleep this Asynctask

           //I want to delay my for loop
        }
     //do something
    } 
}
```

Creating a new Thread isn't what I want as follow:

```
//inside doInBackground()
new Thread(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public run(){
     for(..){
       Thread.sleep(1000);//sleeping for 1 second
     }
  }
});
//other parts
```

**P.S.** I am using **AsyncTask in Service** to run in background every N seconds.

Comment: Do checks based on the system clock, while(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastRunTime < 1000)  //wait... Or something like that

Comment: `Thread.sleep(...)` does not create a new thread.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Yes of course it doesn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `Thread.sleep(1000)` from inside the `doInBackground()` method, this will not affect the UI since `doInBackground()` is called on a background thread.

Comment: :-) You didn't read my question carefully. "Is there any way other than creating a new Thread?"

Comment: How does my answer require creating a new thread? All I'm suggesting is that you should call `Thread.sleep(1000)` inside the `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: Actually I misunderstood your answer :-) Sorry. But that will halt the UI for 1 seconds,right?

Comment: No, it won't halt the UI because `doInBackground()` is called on a background thread. The UI thread will continue to run unaffected as the background thread runs/sleeps in the background. Perhaps you should test it out for yourself. :)

Comment: Doesn't the AsyncTask run on UI thread? So how doInBackground() run on different thread?

Comment: The whole point of an `AsyncTask` is to perform a short asynchronous task on a background thread. The documentation states "`doInBackground(Params...)` is invoked on the background thread immediately after `onPreExecute()` finishes executing." Have you read the `AsyncTask` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

Comment: So I can put "Thread.sleep(2000)" in doInBackground() without any trouble in UI?

Comment: @Nabin Yes. The reason why `AsyncTask` exists in the Android API is so that you can perform tasks (the task is "sleeping for 2000ms" in this case) in the background without affecting the UI.

Comment: 2000? or 1000? a typo?

Comment: You said `1000` in your original question and you said `2000` in your comment. Either way, does it really matter??